# default column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

i'm trying to have a table with a column that has a default value.
right now i can only get this by having a trigger change the value to the default, is it possible to have it declared on the table right from the start?

Would it be possible to have something like the Identity, where i don't have to pass the value into the insert?

egx: insert into Direct values(2)

```
 and the table would become
 id | item
 1  | 2
 the id = 1, would be the deafult value
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create constraints at time of table creation or later.

```
create table
#test
(
id int identity(1,2),
name char(255) default newid(),
code int default 2
)

---if a table contains all default values,you can insert like below
insert into #test
default values

updated as per comments:
 create table
#test1
(
id int identity(1,2),
name char(255) default newid(),
code int default 2,
notdf int
)

---if a table contains one default value and rest all are default
insert into #test1(notdf)
select 2
```

Further if you want to add a default value after table creation you can do it like below

```
create table 
tt1
(
valuue int,
address char(2) not null
)

insert into tt1
select 1,'a'


ALTER TABLE tt1 ADD CONSTRAINT test1 DEFAULT null FOR address;
```

Comment: your first example is really cool, and it only works if they are all default? why? if u have a value that doesnt have a default constraint, and 1 with it, when inserting could i pass just the one without the constraint?

Comment: and can a default value, be in a primary key, or a foreign key constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Use `default`.  You can change an existing column by doing:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT df_t_column DEFAULT 1 for id;
```

An identity is trickier.  I would suggest copying the data over to a temporary table, dropping the table, creating it with an identity column and reloading the data.